# Fix the size of <Pre> and make scrollable in html

Tags: html, css, scroll, pre

I used < Pre > to show my json data in Modal. But < pre > became different size according to the json size. I want to fix the < pre > height. If json is bigger, it will show by scroll.

Here is my Modal .

```
<div class="modal-content json-modal-body" id="full-width" ng-controller="projectdetailsController">

    <div class="modal-header modal-header-confirm">
        <h4 class="modal-title ng-binding">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-indent-left"></span>{{modalOptions.headerText}}
        </h4>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body"> 

         <pre ng-bind-html="json | prettifyFilter"></pre>

    </div>

</div>
```

When the json is empty. It becomes like this 
[image]

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This:

```
<style>
 div.scroll {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
 }
</style>
```

See, if that solves your problem.

Comment: Either add style to div.modal-body or in pre. Whatever works :)

Comment: In that case I would suggest you to put overflow: scroll to parent. Have you tried adding that style to pre? See if that helps

Comment: <pre class="Modal-pre" ng-bind-html="json | prettifyFilter"></pre>

Comment: Are you getting expected output after adding style to your <pre>?

Answer (score 0):

You could set some width, height and force it to always show scroll

```
  .modal-body pre {
    height: 200px;/*something like 90% would work too if parent's height is specified*/
    width: 300px;
    word-wrap: break-word;/*if you want to prevent horizontal scrolling and wrap text instead*/
    overflow: scroll;/*forces scroll to always show; if overflow: auto scroll will be visible only if needed*/
  }
```

Comment: Width looks ok... But height is bigger than my modal...
See the whole Modal html in edited

Comment: Then set width and height to some percentage of parent (if it has width and height). You can use absolute positioning relative to parent and `height: auto` too.

Comment: Parents: .json-modal-body{
 
 width: 900px;
 height: 480px;
 
 
}

Comment: Does something like `90%` work for you? If you want your padding to be independent of parent's size then absolute positioning will do the job.